# PyQt Make Custom PushButton / inheritance from class which has arguments

Tags: python, inheritance, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm new at PyQt I want to build my own Check Box which inheritance from QCheckBox.

```
class Valve(QtGui.QCheckBox):
    def __init__(self, x, y, inputs=[], outputs=[]):
        QtGui.QCheckBox.__init__(self)
        self.sources = inputs
        self.outputs = outputs
        self.move(x, y)

    def is_fillable(self):
        for source in self.sources:
            if source.value == 100: 
                return 1
        return 0

    def stateChanged():
        if isChecked():
            for output in self.outputs:
                if self.is_fillable():
                    output.fill(1)
        else:
            for output in self.outputs:
                if self.is_fillable:
                    output.fill(-1)

class MainWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.button1 = Valve('', self, 5, 6)

        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 500, 500)
        self.show()

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Description what I did here:

I want to build water system. I will use progress bars as pipe so in my code inputs and outputs will be QProgressBar and I will fill them with their values.

However my Valve(CheckBox) is not show up at my Window Because I couldn't figure how to inheritance from QCheckButton out since it has argument.

Thanks for answers

Answer (score 2):

You'd want to pass `MainWindow` as the parent of your checkbox:

```
class Valve(QtGui.QCheckBox):

    def __init__(self, parent, x, y, inputs=[], outputs=[]):
        QtGui.QCheckBox.__init__(self, parent)

class MainWindow(QtGui.QWidget):

    def initUI(self):
        self.button1 = Valve(self, 5, 6)
```